# C# Generic method overloading

Tags: c#, generics

I have problem with C# generics. I need do something like this, in PCL.

```
class Factory<T> : IFactory<T>
{
    T Create()
    {
          throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

class Factory : IFactory<MyClass>
{
    MyClass Create()
    {
         return new MyClass();
    }
}

//In some method ....
IFactory<MyClass> factory = new Factory<MyClass>();
MyClass variable = factory.Create(); //This throw NotSupportedException
```

I know this is bulshit, but I try many solutions and no of them work :-(

Comment: At the moment this doesn't make much sense. You're not even using the non-generic `Factory` class in your example.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Thats why I say this is bulshit, but I can not figure out how can I make this. I need method for few types and for another throw NotSupportedException, but how?

Comment: Any reason you've not used a generic constraint to force there to be a parameterless constructor, and call that, rather than creating a concrete class for each class you'd construct (that your sample doesn't even use)

Comment: @Peter You haven't actually described what you're trying to do. Please add this to your question.

Comment: I need do something like IoC. Contrainer.Resolve<T> but withnout reflection

Comment: Make a non-generic interface that returns `object` and cast.

Comment: How is this different from `Activator.CreateInstant<T>()`?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an instance of `Factory<T>`, not `Factory`. `Factory<T>.Create` throws an exception, so the behavior you're seeing is normal.

You should use `Factory` instead of `Factory<T>`.

Another option is to add a `new` constraint on `T` in `Factory<T>`:

```
class Factory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Create()
    {
          return new T()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Factory<T>` class doesn't serve any purpose in your example, since your `Factory` is inheriting directly from `IFactory<T>`. If you're going to do that, you can just delete the first class, and do this:

```
IFactory<MyClass> factory = new Factory();
MyClass variable = factory.Create();
```

The reason you're getting an exception is because you're creating an instance of `Factory<T>`, and that is defined to throw an exception when `.Create()` is called on it.